# Java Web Start : Track exit of client application

Tags: java

A main class is invoked through a JNLP file using Java Web Start from a client machine. I want to update server DB table based on successful launch and closing of the application in client machine.

The constraint is that I can't modify the application that gets launched(as it is a 3rd party GPL tool)
Per my understanding of JWS, control goes out once application is launched.
Is there any way to track such events(especially closure) using Java Web Start itself ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so - as far as I know webstart doesn't track this these itself.  You could write a simple wrapper application that is launched by webstart, which itself launches the 3rd party app.

Comment: Thks fr quick reply. Problem is third party tool does all things in it's main method itself....so difficult to write wrapper...

Comment: Donno whether you have patience to go thru, but here is the link of 3rd party source code http://www.elusiva.com/opensource/downloads/JavaRDP1.1.tgz and I invoke RDesktopSwing.java thru JNLP

Comment: >> Problem is third party tool does all things in it's main method itself   --- that's not a problem, there's nothing stopping your wrapper class from calling the 3rdparty tool's main method, just like any other method in any other class. BrittishMutt's answer is the correct one.

Comment: My response assumes that you have gone thru RDesktopSwing.java referred above. If you see, the exit is also being called inside main method. My requirement is to tweak-in(update server table) before exit gets called. Per requirement I can't modify  RDesktopSwing.java, hence I'm in a fix !